# How to resolve net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, get, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to do a GET request to my server. I have done it many times previously, and everything was working.

But now, when I launch it on Google Chrome, it gives me this error :

> GET http://myserver.net:443/searchShoplist/apple net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

When I launch it on Firefox, I have no result and no response.

Here is the code of my request to the server :

```
var data = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://myserver.net:443/searchShoplist/apple");
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Is that port correct?  I get no response at that address. Could that service have changed things up recently?

Comment: This address is not the right one. I just gave an example.

Comment: Can you see a response when you type your address into your browser?

Comment: I have : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Wait, you are getting a response in the browser of `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, and you are getting the exact same response from your PHP code, and you want to know what is wrong with your PHP code?  Is that right?  Are you also getting the same error when you try a simple `curl http://.....` request?  So what does that tell you?   oooh.  And I talking just the url, leave the word GET off the request.

Comment: Yes, I get the same error. And in fact, I use javascript to do my request. The exact error of the web browser is : _This website is unreachable. myserver.net does not allow the connection._

Comment: So the site used to work, and now it says `myserver.net does not allow the connection.` Possible the site changed their access rules?  Its not a Yahoo related site, is it? Lots of their stuff has changed dramatically in the past few weeks.  Is that server yours? if not, is there an API guide available to using the site? Is there an API key required?  Is it a paid site? I'm not seeing this as a programming related issue.

Comment: Yes it is my server. So the problem comes from the API itself ?

Comment: that's where I'd start.  You should be able to get a response via simple browser test or via command line `curl` request.  A couple of tools for testing connections include https://requestb.in/ or Postman (in Chrome Browser)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I'll try that.

Comment: "connection refused" means you couldn't set up a TCP connection.  It's probably not your script.  Browsers can sometimes show this if they have invalid proxy settings.